# How do I fix zsh bus error because of anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, bus-error

I'm working on a personal project in python it's taking me weeks of learning to get to this point. It was working just fine until I installed Anaconda to learn jupyter notebook and now, my program won't run. It gives me an error -  `zsh: bus error  python3 -u "/Users/.... "`

I reinstalled all the packages and stuff. It still gives me an error called `zsh bus error`, idk how to fix it and I don't want weeks worth of my progress in the bin. Plus I am not going to copy paste reinstall python and all that stuff again please give me a solution. I'm begging rn. I hate anaconda, It was brought into existence to ruin someone's interest in programming.

Comment: "Bus error" is a whole _class_ of problem -- we can't tell specifically what it is from just that description. You could attach a debugger like gdb to your Python interpreter to find out _exactly_ what's wrong, or we can make some educated guesses -- but those guesses will probably things you somehow think would involve "weeks worth of progress in the bin", like installing a Python interpreter (and set of associated libraries) compiled for the CPU you actually have, vs whatever CPU your upstream distributor chose to build for.

Comment: (mind, I don't see why you think that replacing an interpreter would set you back weeks -- if you're following good practices, such as installing tools and dependencies programmatically as opposed to by hand, it should be a matter of minutes to hours)

Comment: BTW, attaching gdb is a good idea no matter what -- if a library dependency needs to be recompiled, f/e, a C stack trace will typically tell you _exactly what_ that is.

Comment: No because I uninstalled Anaconda now, while my program is now up and running but it is giving my another new never before error- "FutureWarning: Series.__getitem__ treating keys as positions is deprecated. In a future version, integer keys will always be treated as labels (consistent with DataFrame behavior). To access a value by position, use `ser.iloc[pos]`
  if not _np.isnan(quotes["High"][n - 1]) "

Comment: Warnings don't stop things from working; _that's what distinguishes them from errors_. In this case it's a warning telling you that your code will stop working in the future; that's distinct from it not working _now_.

Comment: gotcha, Im just worried that this warning might affect me later on in the program

Comment: Well, yes, it might (not today, but after you update your software stack) -- the message tells you how to fix it, though. If it's not your code but someone else's that's throwing the warning, it's on that someone else to fix and you can ignore it (or check whether their project's bugtracker has a ticket to track the update, if they don't have it fixed already in the active development branch of their tree).

Comment: I'd suggest not filing tickets in OSS projects' bugtrackers until you're in a better headspace to be courteous, though. (Not that there's anything wrong with the way you've interacted in the comments here, but your initial question excudes annoyance).

Comment: Lmaoo yeah my b i was annoyed. im a clg student its basically a personal project im using yfinance api. Thanks for the help Imma try to use anaconda later when I have a good idea of what its supposed to do rn imma just work on what I have going on